# What is the idea behind h2-h3?

Tags: pawns

[image]

The pawn move from `h2` to `h3`. I do not understand the reason behind this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a **common** idea in the position. It's there to prevent `Be3 Ng4`. Allowing Ng4 with the bishop on e3 is not good; White's dark bishop should be exchanged with Black's strong g7-bishop, something like `Be3-Qd2-Bh6` or `Be3-Bd4-Bxg7`.

Please note White played `10.Be3` immediately next. Without `9.h3`, something like this would have happened:

```
9.Be3 Ng4! 10.Qe2 Nxe3!
```

Black's position is fine with the strong g7 
bishop unchallenged. `9.h3` is a good move.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer 9. h3 to 9. f3?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, and it has to do mainly with king safety and not wanting to weaken one's own position. in general, playing h3 instead of f3 is a bit safer for white's king if white ever wants to castle short, since it doesn't open up a long diagonal from a7 to g1. Moreover, a pawn on f2 guards the e3 square which makes it easier for white to keep control over some key dark squares in their position.